# $k$ dimensional cake numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I am wondering whether there is a generalization of the sequence [A000125](https://oeis.org/A000125) to the $k$ dimensional case of cutting an $k$ dimensional cake with $n$ hyperplanes. For three dimensions, in the comments of the squence on OEIS the form is given as

$$a(n,3) = \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3}.$$

Can this be generalized to $k$ dimensions via

$$a(n,k) = \sum_{l=0}^k\binom{n}{l}?$$

I haven't found any sources on this topic.

Comment: Have you checked whether your formula works for $n=1$ and $2$? Have you checked that the first $n$ cuts according to your formula all result in powers of $2$? Those would be the first things I would do to see if the formula is reasonable.